# Using PCA covariance for linear regression

Tags: regression, pca

$X$ be a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^p$ and $Y$ a random variable, both with mean zero.

Let $\Sigma$ denote their joint covariance matrix:
$$ 
\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}\Sigma_X & \Sigma_{XY} \\ \Sigma_{YX} & \sigma_Y^2\end{pmatrix}
$$

The conditional expectation is given by
$$ \mathbb{E}[Y|X] = \Sigma_{YX} \Sigma_X^{-1} X$$

This coincides with ordinary least squares regression when $\Sigma$ is estimated as the sample covariance.

Suppose that $\Sigma$ is estimated with some form of shrinkage. That should correspond to regularized linear regression.

For example, suppose that
$$ \Sigma = (1-\lambda) S + \lambda I $$
where $S$ is sample covariance.

Then
$$ \hat{\beta} = \left(S_{X} + \frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}I \right)^{-1} S_{XY}$$
which corresponds to Ridge regression.

My question is: what sort of regression do we get if we estimate $\Sigma$ by a low-rank plus scalar:
$$ WW' + \sigma^2 I$$

Comment: I'd have to check the math to be sure if it is the same, but superficially this reminds me of redundancy analysis.